# Data Analytics Approach

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, data-science

I have a dataset of fresh graduate employees with their GPA scores and whether they were hired or fired after Probation period. I was asked by the boss to analyse whether the university GPA has any significant effect on being hired or fired. Sometimes additional features can also be included like university ranking and etc. Boss is now a days interested in data science and machine learning. But I haven't had any prior experience in data analytics  So just give me a heads up into how i can approach this problem and what i should learn to do this? I have programming background (know python) so technical jargons are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

In these , you are basically trying to predict whether the university GPA,university ranking and etc has any significant effect on being hired or fired after Probation period. Basically it is Binary classification problem (for complete tutorial on these [Binary Classification Best Tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/)).
The approach given by @janu777 is correct , i wanted to add some additional information in that.
The steps for solving these problem is ,

```
Data Exploration(include variable identifications)
Data Cleaning
Feature Engineering(Watching correlations kind of property among features)
Model Building and Training 
Doing Predictions
```

Basically from python side you will use these libraries

```
Pandas
Scikit Learn
Matplotlib
numpy
Sklearn
Statsmodelapi
```

**Data Exploration:**
Firstly you should have previous years data(whether previous employee was hired or fired) as train set .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv("../trainset.csv") #Reading the dataset in a dataframe 
df.describe()
```

**Data Cleaning**

Now in these stage you should have to see missing values and all in your data and you can do treatment according to your choice , most famous is to drop all missing values , so for that you can use these ,

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

I am assuming that your train set have 3 variable in which university GPA and university ranking is feature variable . and your target variable is hired/fired(1 or 0) . you should use correlation among your predictor and target variable and also visualization will be helpful.

```
trainingdata['GPA'].astype('float64').corr(trainingdata['target'].astype('float64'))
```

or

```
# importing the required module
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x axis values
x = [1,2,3] # your feature variable
# corresponding y axis values
y = [2,4,1] # your target variable

# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y)

# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis')

# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('My first graph!')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

**Model Building and predictions and fitting**
That is very important stage , now you need to create model for your problem and you can use these algorithms [Sklearn algo](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning)(you should apply vaious algorithms as Randomforest,lineardiscriminate,decisiontree,knn,svm etc and choose only that algorithm which gives good score)
sample code for these is ,

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#Building random forest classifier model
def random_forest_classifier(features, target):
    """
    To train the random forest classifier with features and target data
    :param features:
    :param target:
    :return: trained random forest classifier
    """
    clf = RandomForestClassifier()
    clf.fit(features, target)
    return clf
```

**Doing Predictions**
Now you can do prediction on your test data , sample code for the same is ,

```
   predictions = randomforestmodelis.predict(test_x)
    for i in range(0, 5):
        print("Actual outcome :: {} and Predicted outcome :: {}".format(list(test_y)[i], predictions[i]))
        #print("Train Accuracy :: ", accuracy_score(train_y, randomforestmodelis.predict(train_x)))
    print("Test Accuracy  :: ", accuracy_score(test_y, predictions))
```

That should solve your problem .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I got few new information about the problem. The real goal of doing this is to prove to the management whether the cost can be saved by keeping GPA as a benchmark for hiring by showing that people with high GPA are getting hired  overwhelmingly after probation. So isn't this just a statistical visualisation problem and it has nothing to do with prediction(machine learning) ?

Comment: In that case , you should go with feature analysis using correlation kind of methods and you can use visualization like in matplotlib .

Comment: If you can share any links or other resources to learn feature analysis and correlation, it would be helpful for me to learn.

Comment: definatly you can look here https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-correlation-learn-data-science-tutorials and also https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-scratch/ and a lot of tutorials you will surely find like kaggle , analyticsvidhya and on udacity,courseera,datascienceacademy etc

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to predict the employment status of fresh graduates given their GPA, University_ranking etc as features.

Your problem can be considered as a "Binary Classification problem" since your output should be fired/hired as (0 or 1)

**Training_set**: First of all you need to create a training set with features and their actual output.

**Feature Analysis:** Try to analyze how the data is affecting the output using something like this:

```
train = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv')
print (train[["GPA", "Employment_status"]].groupby(['GPA'], as_index=False).mean())
```

**Algorithm to train:** There are many machine learning algorithms that can be used to solve binary classification problems like SVM, Decision trees, KNN. 
You can also go for anomaly detection where you can fit a distribution with one of the outputs.
Use sklearn libraries, because they are easy to use and also provide a large variety of algorithms.

Check [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) to learn more about sklearn.

**Testing:** Finally test your model with a test set and calculate the accuracy to see how the model has fit the data.

Check out the lectures by andrew ng as they are very easy to understand for anyone who is starting machine learning.Find it [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)

**Data Visualization:**

Kaggle is one of the best platforms to learn new approaches and algorithms Check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/jananesekaran/python-data-visualizations) link as it provides information about how to use different data visualization tools on Iris dataset.

Check [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/datavisualization) MOOC to learn more about data visualizations.

Data Visualizations will thereby help you understand how your features are correlated.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I got few new information about the problem. The real goal of doing this is to prove to the management that whether the cost can be saved by keeping GPA as a benchmark for hiring by showing that people with high GPA are getting hired  overwhelmingly after probation. So isn't this just a statistical visualisation problem and it has nothing to do with prediction(machine learning) ?

Comment: Then you should just take the feature analysis step. Categorize the GPA as high for values above some threshold and low for values below that and check the percent of impact also you can visualize this by plotting.

Comment: If you can share any links or other resources to learn feature analysis and correlation, it would help for me to learn.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please do check out Kaggle platform as it is very useful for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

**Random Forest** is perhaps the most popular classification algorithm, capable of both classification and regression. It can accurately classify large volumes of data. The name “Random Forest” is derived from the fact that the algorithm is a combination of decision trees